# Print filename and columns with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to select the column 23,24 and 27 of the 8th row.

Here is the way I have tried.

```
awk 'FNR == 8 {print $23,$24,$37}' file.txt
```

It works perfectly. 
However, I'm wondering how to add the corresponding file name as the $0

Then, the output should look like

```
file.txt colunm23 colunm24 colunm 27     <---- The 8th row.
```

I'm not using gawk. Please suggest based on the version before gawk 4.0.0
Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Use the [`FILENAME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset) variable:

```
awk 'FNR == 8 {print FILENAME,$23,$24,$37}' file.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

awk 'FNR == 8 {print $23,$24,$37}' file.txt

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.